# problem in memory allocation for array of objects in iphone SDK?

Tags: iphone

if i do like,i know its wrong, but can anyone give alternative solution?

```
for(int i = 0;i<=3;i++)
{
  myclass *obj[i] = [[myclass alloc] init];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's kinda hard to tell, since you give no indication of what you're trying to do. Here's my best guess:

```
myclass *obj[4];
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    obj[i] = [[myclass alloc] init];
}
```

(Note also the change to `i < 4`. Since the end result is to loop four times, not three, it is bad form to say `i <= 3`.)